# ¿Cómo detectar click en un ListView?

Tags: java, android

Lo que quiero hacer es, de un `ListView` agregarle un `OnClickListener` para poder abrir la información del contacto a otra actividad, estilo una agenda telefónica de celular.

Comment: Tienes ya tu ListView en el Layout, podrías agregar tu código para poder dar más detalles, saludos.

Answer (score 6):

Sería bastante similar al `onClickListener` de un botón.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapter, View view, int position, long arg) {

       Intent telefono = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TuActividadParaElTelefono.class);
       startActivity(telefono);
    }
});
```

donde `TuActividadParaElTelefono` sería la Actividad a la que vas a llamar cuando des click a cada uno de los elementos del `ListView`. Con el parámetro `position` podrás saber en que elemento estás en cada momento para lanzar una Actividad u otra.

También, si todo el rato vas a llamar a la misma actividad pero van a cambiar los datos que se van a mostrar (supongo que con un acceso a base de datos) le puedes pasar la posición del elemento en el que estás al `Intent` y recuperar los datos en la Actividad en función a esa posición mediante:

```
telefono.putExtra("posicion", position);
```

justo antes de empezar la Actividad.

Para recuperar estos datos en la actividad tendrías que usar lo siguiente:

```
Intent telefonoRecuperado = getIntent();
telefonoRecuperado.getStringExtra("posicion"));
```

Comment: Por favor, ¿alguien me puede explicar el voto negativo?

Answer (score 3):

Esto es una pregunta similar que puedes encontrar en SO en español,

#### A tu `ListView` debes asignar el el listener:  [**`setOnItemClickListener`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener))

Este es un ejemplo de como realizarlo,

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

  //Mediante un Intent configuramos la Activity a abrir.  
  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityInformacion.class);
  //Se agrega en el Bundle información del contacto.
  intent.putExtra("contacto", Contacto.get(position).geContacto());
  //Inicia Intent.
  startActivity(intent);

  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que yo eh hecho y me ha servido es lo siguiente en el inicio implementar el `setOnItemClickListener`:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Una vez teniendo esto implementar los métodos de la función, generas un `Intent` para poder arrastrar toda la información necesaria del contacto.

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent i= new Intent(getActivity(), VisualizacionDatos.class);
    i.putExtra("contacto",Contacto.get(position).geContacto());
    startActivity(i);
}
```

La clase `VisualizacionDatos`, es otra actividad donde esta nos mostrara el contacto completo:

```
TextView contacto;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_visualizacion_datos);
    contacto=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactoText);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    contacto.setText(i.getStringExtra("contacto"));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MostrarInformacionActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```