# Ayuda con android studio diversas activitys,obtencion de datos

Tags: java, android, api

Tengo un programa de 2 actividades, la actividad inicial es un logueo que se conecta a una bd mediante control remoto, establece la conexión si el user y el password son correctas.

Ahora bien en la actividad dos necesito que me muestre en un `TextView` el nombre de user que inició sesión. ¿Cómo hago eso?

Dejo aquí parte del código para que os hagáis una idea:

**Actividad 1** todo correcto funciona excepciones incluidas y conecta a la bd

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Connection conn;
    Button btnlogin;
    EditText euser,epass;
    TextView tuser,tpass;
    String[]usuarios;
    String CUsuario;
    String Pwd;
    Boolean prueba=false,prueba2=false;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnAceptar);
        euser=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.TxtUsuario);
        epass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TxtPassword);
        tuser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        tpass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);

        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Pwd= epass.getText().toString();
                CUsuario=euser.getText().toString();
                Login tarea6=new Login(euser.getText().toString(),epass.getText().toString());
                tarea6.execute();
            }
        });
    }

    private class Login extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {

        public Login(String usuario, String contraseña) {
            super();
        }
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String...usuario) {
            conn = DBConnection.getInstance().getConnection();
            try {
                prueba = false;
                prueba2=false;
                String stsql = "SELECT CUsuario,Pwd FROM dbo.xUser WHERE CUsuario='"+CUsuario+"' or Pwd='"+Pwd+"'";
                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(stsql);

                    while (rs.next()) {

                        if(CUsuario.equals(rs.getString(1)) && Pwd.equals(rs.getString(2))) {
                            prueba = true;
                            CUsuario = rs.getString(1);
                            Pwd = rs.getString(2);
                        }
                        else if(CUsuario.equals(rs.getString(1))) {
                            prueba2=true;

                         }
                        }
                }catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            publishProgress(100);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);

            if (CUsuario.equals("") || Pwd.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inserta un usuario y una contraseña", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                euser.setText("");
                epass.setText("");
            }

            else if (prueba==true) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "acceso permitido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                euser.setText("");
                epass.setText("");
                Intent siguiente = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                siguiente.putExtra(CUsuario, euser.getText().toString());
                startActivity(siguiente);
                prueba=false; 
            }
            else if ((prueba == false)&&(prueba2==false)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "contraseña y usuario incorrectos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                euser.setText("");
                epass.setText("");
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "usuario correcto,contraseña incorrecta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                epass.setText("");
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {//este es para interactuar con la interfaz grafica mientras esta en ejecucion la tarea asyncrona
            int progreso = values[0].intValue();
        }

    }
```

**Actividad 2**

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity {
  Button btn1,btn2,btn3;
    public TextView t1;
    Connection conn3,conn;
    String[]llamadas;
    int IdLlamada;
    Date Fecha;
    String Mensaje;
    String De;
    String IdUsuarioDestino;
    String NombreUsuario;
    String CUsuario;
    boolean Estado;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
        btn1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btnllamadasatendidas);
        btn2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btnllamadasperdidas);
        btn3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btncerrar);
        NombreUsuario=getIntent().getExtras().getString(CUsuario);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String user= intent.getStringExtra( NombreUsuario);
        t1.setText(user);
```

Creo que el fallo está en el nombre de usuario en el `CUsuario` no me deja obtener el `EUser` de la otra actividad y pase `CUsuario` y está vacío, ¿alguna solución?

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es mandar información de una Activity a otra no?

Comment: No sé si es duplicada o no así que lo dejo en un comentario para que la comunidad decida. La pregunta no es igual pero el propósito de la misma es muy parecido: pasar datos de una Actividad a otra. Te dejo el link: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/28741/c%C3%B3mo-detectar-click-en-un-listview/28750#28750

Comment: lo que quiero mandar es la informacion de la actividad uno concretamente el usuario a un textview de la actividad2

Comment: Entonces puedes mirar el link que te he pasado sin centrarte en lo del onclick. Simplemente en como se pasa con el Intent la información de una actividad a otra. Luego en la segunda (cuando recuperes el valor) podrás insertarlo en el textview.

Answer (score 5):

El problema es que el nombre de la llave en la preferencia la estas modificando, cuando envíes un dato define un nombre de llave y al recibir obtienes del [bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) el mismo valor.

Realiza de esta forma el [`Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html):

```
  Intent siguiente = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
  //siguiente.putExtra(CUsuario, euser.getText().toString());
  siguiente.putExtra("usuario", euser.getText().toString());
  startActivity(siguiente);
```

al recibir el valor de "usuario" en la otra `Activity`, simplemente define el nombre de la llave del valor que deseas obtener:

```
NombreUsuario = getIntent().getExtras().getString("usuario");
```

o simplemente:

```
NombreUsuario = getIntent().getStringExtra("usuario");
```

de esta forma la variable `NombreUsuario`  en tu clase `Main2Activity`, se obtendrá correctamente.

---

### Como enviar datos entre Activities.

Para realizar el envió de datos se realiza generalmente mediante un `Bundle` en el cual se pueden agregar valores y ese `bundle` se envía a través de un `Intent`. Se puede especificar el envió de cualquier tipo de elemento o array de elemento especificando el nombre:

```
    intent.putExtra("usuario", "StackOverflow!");
    intent.putExtra("id", 123);
    intent.putExtra("myByte", 0xa);
    intent.putExtra("latitud", 0.12324234);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Los valores se obtienen en la `Activity` que recibe el `Bundle` mediante [getExtras()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras()) o el [método especifico para obtener tipo de dato recibido](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). Retorna null si no encuentra valor.

```
String valor = getIntent().getExtras().getString("usuario");
```

o simplemente:

```
String valor = getIntent().getStringExtra("usuario");
```

Comment: Es correcta +1.

Comment: Muchas gracias, la he actualizado aún con más información.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que no te está cogiendo el valor porque en la Main2Activity el valor de CUsuario no es el mismo que en la MainActivity, por lo que no encontrará dicho parámetro al intentar recuperarlo.

En el MainActivity estás mandando la información al Main2Activity de la siguiente forma:

```
String CUsuario;
CUsuario = euser.getText().toString();
.....
Intent siguiente = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
siguiente.putExtra(CUsuario, euser.getText().toString());
```

Y en el Main2Activity la estás recogiendo de esta forma:

```
String CUsuario;
NombreUsuario = getIntent().getExtras().getString(CUsuario);
```

Para resolverlo deberías utilizar un nombre constante para que se pueda encontrar el valor que le estas pasando desde el MainActivity. Quedando el código de la siguiente forma:

**MainActivity**:

```
siguiente.putExtra("usuario", euser.getText().toString());
```

**Main2Activity**:

```
NombreUsuario = getIntent().getExtras().getString("usuario");
```

Comment: ¿porque me dan -1 varias personas? si la respuesta es correcta, no lo entiendo

Comment: Por qué compites con una mujer :u, siempre perdemos jajaja
pd: yo te di +1

Comment: el caso es que me han dado un -2 sin ningún motivo y sin dar explicación, si estuviera mal la respuesta o se desviara del tema preguntado lo entendería, pero siendo que la compañera @Elenasys ha respondido lo mismo que yo y a ella también le han quitado, no lo entiendo

Comment: Hahaha! como que compiten con una mujer, os hombre siempre ganan! ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡° )

Comment: jajajja, yo sólo he intentado dar una respuesta correcta, pero por lo visto no lo he hecho tan bien